# Global variables defined inside a class

Tags: python

I found a solution to Leetcode NO. 543 Diameter of Binary Tree which is solved with the use of global variables. I have the solution shown in the text below. The author used a scalar variable, 'self.res', to store the final answer which is updated when the program traverses through the given binary tree.

I am wondering why the author needs to use `self.res` rather than a generic integer variable---for example, `res` only---to store the answer; when I replace self.res with res, the answer is wrong. Can anyone point out the difference?

```
class Solution:
    def diameterOfBinaryTree(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        self.res = 0 
        def depth(root):
            if not root:
                return 0
            left = depth(root.left)
            right = depth(root.right)
            self.res = max(self.res, left + right) 
            return max(left, right) + 1
        depth(root)    
        return self.res
```

Comment: it's a matter of variable scope. If you declare `global res` right after `def depth`, it should work as in the original solution

Comment: `res` doesn't have to be global; `depth` has access to local variables defined in the same scope.

Comment: @Demi-Lune I see. Then, I am wondering what is the difference between declaring the self.res as the object's attribute right after `class Solution:` and declaring it as the author did inside a particular method `diameterOfBinaryTree`. Is it just a matter of programming taste?

Comment: There's no instance outside of the instance method. That said, there's no particular reason for the class `Solution` to exist, or for `diameterOfBinaryTree` to be a method rather than an ordinary function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it doesn't have to be an attribute. It could be a non-local variable.

```
class Solution:
    def diameterOfBinaryTree(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        res = 0
        def depth(root):
            nonlocal res
            if not root:
                return 0
            left = depth(root.left)
            right = depth(root.right)
            res = max(res, left + right) # the key to memorize the result
            return max(left, right) + 1
        depth(root)    
        return res
```

Without the `nonlocal` statement, `res` would be a local variable that isn't set the first time `depth` tries to use it in the call to `max`.

Python 2 did not have a `nonlocal` statement, so an instance attribute would have been the best alternative to a global variable for persisting state between calls to `depth`. (The type hints indicate this probably wasn't written for Python 2, but old habits can die hard.) In Python 3, using `nonlocal`, the above no longer even uses `self`, so `diameterOfBinaryTree` can trivially be written as a regular function rather than an instance method of an unnecessary class.